# Python loop enter page X times

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, selenium

I have code that need to go to pages and copy links in loop when I do from page 1 to 14.
My question : Why its **only** show page 14 links its should show page 1-14 links

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

for x in range(1, 14):
 driver.get("http://xxxx.com/pages?page=%d" % (x))
text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxALL']/article/a" )
for link in text:
    print (link.get_attribute("href"))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

print (len(text))
```

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question.

Comment: All of your code after the for loop needs to be indented..  your loop will only get the last page and then the rest of the code runs

Comment: @AK47 I dont know what do you mean by that , I am new in python

Comment: This might help with your question about indentation: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php

Comment: See my answer @MaorBenLulu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent all of your code to be inside the `for x in range(14)`: otherwise it wont run 14 times:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

for x in range(1, 14):
    driver.get("http://xxxx.com/pages?page=%d" % (x))
    text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxALL']/article/a" )
    for link in text:
        print (link.get_attribute("href"))
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    print (len(text))
```

Comment: for link in text:
        links = link.get_attribute("href")
driver.get(links) 
sex = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/h1")
print(sex.text)